# custom fields for wordpress with new WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

i want to add custom fields value in this code

```
<?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=20;&posts_per_page=5' ); ?>
```

i need to replace the number 20 with custom fields value

this code for display custom fields

```
<?php $references = get_post_meta($post->ID, "references",true); ?>
<?php echo $references ?>
```

is there any way to add

```
<?php echo $references ?>
```

to the code so `cat=<?php echo $references ?>` or some thing like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want, you can do something like this:

"Simplest Form", but liable to break if things aren't set / correct in your custom field:

```
// load the category id
$references = (int)get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'references', TRUE);
// use the category id in the query
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=' . $references . ';&posts_per_page=5' );
```

Somewhat better:

```
// use an array for the parameters.  Set it up here
$parameters = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
);

// load the category id
$references = (int)get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'references', TRUE);

// only if there is a reference ID, add it to the parameters
if ( $references ) {
    $parameters['cat'] = $references;
)

// pass the parameters into the WP_Query
$catquery = new WP_Query( $parameters );
```

Comment: thank you very much the two codes worked perfectly
just for note for the second one code in first line
$parameters = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5,
); i changed }; to ); and worked